# how to migrate perlbrew to other debian server

Tags: perl, module, cpan, perlbrew

Im new to perl.
I have a debian server with perlbrew istallation.
There is a custom module which a want on new debian server.
Module is owned by my company.

What is the best way to achieve funktional module?
I was able to start the module and install dependencies via cpan, but (i think) the variables like $PATH and $PERLBREW_HOME are wrong so i cant start it via bash-script like on the old server // somehing like use PERLBREW passing MODULENAME

Comment: What you want to do is not what perlbrew is for. If your script has fixed library paths in it you need to change them to where those libs are on the new machine. If your custom modules have fixed paths in them, you need to create those on the new machine, unless your developers did something less than ideal, in which case you need to change them (not the debs, the paths) and pray. You always need to install your application dependencies. If you don't want to mess with the system Perl, perlbrew is one easy but overkill for production option to get another Perl on your system.

Comment: I did copy the full perlbrew folder to new machine. and updated the variables.

Comment: I did copy the full perlbrew folder to new machine. I needed to update some variables like $PATH $PERLBREW_HOME etc.. Call me lucky there where a ini script in /etc/perlbrew which contained those varibles. I needed to edit bash .profile to alter PATH permanently. There where two old libraries needed, which i simply copied to the path, where the module expected them. thanks for reply.

Comment: So it works now? Please consider adding a proper answer of how you fixed it for future reference.